# Javascript regexp expression that matches two digits in a string with optional decimal places

Tags: javascript, regex

How would I modify the following javascript regexp so that it matches all of the proceeding patterns?

```
/(\d\d).+?(\d\d)/

2 of 5
2.5 of 5.6
2.3 of 10
100.4 of 1000
1000.4 of 10000.3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?).+?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/
```

This will match one or more decimals followed by an optional decimal point and one or more decimals, captured in group 1, followed by one or more of any character, non-greedily, followed by one or more decimals followed by an optional decimal point and one or more decimals, captured in group 2.

[**Demonstration**](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28%5Cd%2b%28?%3a%5C.%5Cd%2b%29?%29.%2b?%28%5Cd%2b%28?%3a%5C.%5Cd%2b%29?%29&input=2%20of%205%0A2.5%20of%205.6%0A2.3%20of%2010%0A100.4%20of%201000%0A1000.4%20of%2010000.3)

Also, if you want to prevent any other characters before or after the matched string, you may need to add a start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchor:

```
/^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?).+?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$/
```

Comment: What's the `?:` purpose?

Comment: I believe that is a non-capturing group?

Comment: @cvsguimaraes It creates a non-capturing group. They may not be needed, but I'm using that to ensure that OP's groups still return what seems to be expected (group 1 contains the first number, group 2 the second).

Comment: @cvsguimaraes Thanks bud, I will accept the appropriate answer once I'm sure it solves the problem at hand.  But thanks for the beginner's lesson.

Answer (score 1):

```
/\d+(\.\d+)? of \d+(\.\d+)?/
```

1. `\d+` at least one digit
2. `(\.\d+)?` with optional decimals
3. `of` the string between these two numbers
4. `\d+` followed by at least one digit
5. `\d+` with optional decimals